# How does this C code for finding Josephus number work?

Tags: c, trace

I was writing code that calculates the Josephus number. I was just experimenting with the numbers to get the code right. This is the code I wrote:

```
int answer(int n, int k) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (answer(n - 1, k) + k + 1) % n + 1;
    }
}
```

This is correct (I always keep `k = 0`), but now I don't know why.

I tried tracing it manually, but didn't get the same answer.

This is how I think it works:

`answer(2,0)` => `((answer(1,0))+1)%3` => `((((answer(0,0))+1)%2)+1)%3` => `((1%2)+1)%3` => `(1+1)%3` => `2`.

However, the answer is `1`.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go down :

`answer(2,0)` => return `((answer(1,0))+1)%2 + 1`

`answer(1,0)` =>  return `((answer(0,0))+1)%1+ 1`

`answer(0,0)` => return `0`

- Go up:

`answer(1,0)` =>  return `(0+1)%1+ 1 which is  1`

`answer(2,0)` => return `(1+1)%2 + 1 which is 1`

Comment: Its 1 because 1%1 = 0. I understand it now. Thanks!! :D